# Makefile: All .cpp and .h files in src dir

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm struggling to create a makefile that would work with all the .cpp and .h files in one src directory. I've found numerous answered questions about makefile and directories, but they all had a very complicated directory structure so I didn't really get an answer from those. So far I have this:

```
CXX=g++
LD=g++
CXXFLAGS=-Wall -pedantic -std=c++14 -Wno-long-long -O0 -ggdb
LDLIBS=-lncurses

SRCDIR=src
OBJECTS=answer.o handler.o main.o question.o quiz.o ui.o uiCreateQuiz.o uiImportExport.o uiPrinter.o uiSolveQuiz.o

all: quiz run

compile: quiz

quiz: $(OBJECTS)
    $(LD) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp $(SRCDIR)/%.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

run:
    valgrind ./quiz

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECTS) quiz

answer.o: answer.cpp answer.h
handler.o: handler.cpp handler.h quiz.h question.h answer.h
main.o: main.cpp ui.h handler.h quiz.h question.h answer.h uiPrinter.h uiSolveQuiz.h uiCreateQuiz.h uiImportExport.h
question.o: question.cpp question.h answer.h
quiz.o: quiz.cpp quiz.h question.h answer.h
ui.o: ui.cpp ui.h handler.h quiz.h question.h answer.h uiPrinter.h uiSolveQuiz.h uiCreateQuiz.h uiImportExport.h
uiCreateQuiz.o: uiCreateQuiz.cpp uiCreateQuiz.h handler.h quiz.h question.h answer.h uiPrinter.h
uiImportExport.o: uiImportExport.cpp uiImportExport.h handler.h quiz.h question.h answer.h uiPrinter.h
uiPrinter.o: uiPrinter.cpp uiPrinter.h
uiSolveQuiz.o: uiSolveQuiz.cpp uiSolveQuiz.h handler.h quiz.h question.h answer.h uiPrinter.h
```

the result is:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'answer.cpp', needed by 'answer.o'.  Stop.
```

What should I change to make this work?

Comment: Putting all source code in `src/` might be a poor practice, and is not a universal one. If you insist doing that, code the right `Makefile` (which probably should mention `src/answer.cpp` & `src/answer.h` and maybe even `src/answer.o`, not just `answer.cpp` & `answer.h`)

Comment: Wouldn't this put the .o files in the src directory? I would like to have them in the parent directory (the one where the makefile is).

Comment: So code the good `Makefile` for that. Take a few hours to read the [GNU `make` documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html). Notice that StackOverflow is not a *debug-my-code* service (and you did not exactly explain what you want to do in your question). See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50469800/841108)

Comment: Better to use `vpath` to find the sources.  BTW, you don't want to link like that (you'll omit the standard C++ libraries).  Thankfully, in GNU Make you can write `quiz: $(OBJECTS)` and `quiz: LINK.o=$(LINK.cc)` and the default rule will be fine (just like you don't need to write the command for you `%.o: %.cpp` rule).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp $(SRCDIR)/%.h

answer.o: answer.cpp answer.h
```

`answer.o` depends on `$(SRCDIR)/answer.cpp`, `$(SRCDIR)/answer.h`, `answer.cpp` and `answer.h`.  Make can't find them all.

The easiest way to get what you want (assuming GNU Make) is to use `VPATH` to tell it to search `$(SRCDIR)` for pre-requisites:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wno-long-long
CXXFLAGS += -O0 -ggdb
LIBS += -lncurses

OBJECTS = answer.o handler.o main.o question.o quiz.o ui.o
OBJECTS += uiCreateQuiz.o uiImportExport.o uiPrinter.o uiSolveQuiz.o

VPATH = src

all: run
compile: quiz

quiz: $(OBJECTS)
quiz: LINK.o=$(LINK.cc)

run: quiz
    valgrind ./quiz

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJECTS) quiz

answer.o: answer.cpp answer.h
handler.o: handler.cpp handler.h quiz.h question.h answer.h
main.o: main.cpp ui.h handler.h quiz.h question.h answer.h uiPrinter.h
main.o: uiSolveQuiz.h uiCreateQuiz.h uiImportExport.h
question.o: question.cpp question.h answer.h
quiz.o: quiz.cpp quiz.h question.h answer.h
ui.o: ui.cpp ui.h handler.h quiz.h question.h answer.h uiPrinter.h
ui.o: uiSolveQuiz.h uiCreateQuiz.h uiImportExport.h
uiCreateQuiz.o: uiCreateQuiz.cpp uiCreateQuiz.h handler.h quiz.h
uiCreateQuiz.o: question.h answer.h uiPrinter.h
uiImportExport.o: uiImportExport.cpp uiImportExport.h handler.h quiz.h
uiImportExport.o: question.h answer.h uiPrinter.h
uiPrinter.o: uiPrinter.cpp uiPrinter.h
uiSolveQuiz.o: uiSolveQuiz.cpp uiSolveQuiz.h handler.h quiz.h
uiSolveQuiz.o: question.h answer.h uiPrinter.h
```

(I've made a few minor improvements - e.g. `run` depends on `quiz`, or you'll get a surprise when you `make -j run`, and I've used the standard `$(RM)` variable for portability).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my makefile structure that I worked out over the years:

```
CXX=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -Wextra -Weffc++
LDFLAGS=-lall_my_libs    
SOURCES= \
    all/my/cpp/files.cpp \
    ...

OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:src/%.cpp=bin/%.o)
DEPS=$(OBJECTS:bin/%.o=bin/%.d)

all: my_binary

-include $(DEPS)

my_binary: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS)

bin/%.o: src/%.cpp
    $(CXX) -MD $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -rf bin/*.o bin/*.d my_binary
```

You can have the source files inside an `src` Directory. and the binaries are put inside a bin Directory.

About the include files: The `-MD` compiler pption generates dependency files (*.d) which can be included using the `-include $(DEPS)` Option. This way you don't have to worry about them anymore.